# Usar un condicional if sin un if o else

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando con un sistema que tiene un log in y me encontré con la duda de qué pasa si en un condicional if dejo vació el if o el else como en este caso:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['role'])){
 
}else{
    header('location: login.php');
}
```

O al revés

```
if(isset($_SESSION['role'])){
   header('location: login.php');
}else{
   
}
```

El código sí cumple con lo que quiero, pero estoy seguro en que no es la forma correcta de programarlo. Espero que me puedan explicar un poco más acerca de esto así como otras alternativas que puedan solucionar el problema.
Gracias.

Comment: If no es un ciclo sino un condicional

Comment: Imagínate estas dos frase en lenguaje natural: "Hijo, si no llueve, nada, pero si llueve llévate el paraguas". "Hijo, si llueve llévate el paraguas, pero si no llueve, nada". ¿No será más fácil decir simplemente: "Hijo, si llueve llévate el paraguas"

Comment: En tu segundo ejemplo si role si esta definida ¿por qué lo mandas de nuevo al login?

Comment: Lo puse como ejemplo, mi duda era si es eficiente trabajar de esa manera

Comment: Aparte de lo ya dicho,  conviene saber qué debe ocurrir cuando no hay `role`, para una respuesta óptima. Aquí se podría usar un ternario si debe ocurrir una redirección en ambos casos.

Comment: @A.Cedano y me parece que el [operador de fusión null ayudaría también *creo*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php)

Comment: @BetaM sí. Aunque yo lo suelo usar poco debido a que no funciona en algunas versiones de PHP.

Answer (score -1):

El uso de IF no es un ciclo si no una condicional como bien te dijeron ya, la forma mas correcta a mi ver seria

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['role']) || $_SESSION['role'] !== 'role requerido'){
   header('location: login.php');
   die();
}

// aquí todo tu código en caso de que no se cumpla la condición
```

Comment: @A.Cedano, `header()` solo envía un encabezado, sin finalizar la ejecución del script, es posible que el navegador no llegue a ver lo que pasó en la petición, pero PHP continuará ejecutándose.

Comment: Quizás puedas prescindir del die() pero como bien dice @Triby el código continua ejecutándose, por lo que puede haber alguna interferencia y no realizar la dirección, por ende puedes pero no deberías de prescindir del el.

Comment: No, nada de eso el usuario no debe saber nunca que fue lo que ocurrió mal, el simple hecho de regresarte o mandarte a hacer login basta para que sepa que no tiene los permisos adecuados, sea usuario, contraseña u otra cosa... es algo que el usuario no debe conocer, esto por seguridad y evitar ataques al sitio web.

Comment: Le digo eso a mi auditor de seguridad y me manda por un tubo obligándome a eliminar cualquier mensaje que indique cual fue el problema, pero bueno, dejemos en que es una discusión basada en especulaciones acorde nuestra experiencia y se esta saliendo de contexto, quizás no atañan estos puntos al planteamiento del OP

Comment: Bueno rectifico. [Aquí hay una respuesta interesante](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2747791/5587982) donde se indica que efectivamente, para este caso de redirecciones conviene usar `die()` o `exit()`. Me retracto de lo dicho y borro comentarios para no confundir a OP. He aprendido algo nuevo. Gracias por las aclaraciones.